# Summing an array of integers, two styles

Tags: c, array, comparative-review

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int *arr, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum = sum + *arr;
        arr = arr + 1;  
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumx(int *arr, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4};
    printf("%i\n", sum(myArray,4));  // prints 10
    printf("%i\n", sumx(myArray,4)); // prints 10
    return 0;
}
```

Which implementation between sum and sumx is "best way"?

Comment: The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.
  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at
  concrete code in a real context. Please see [_Why
  is hypothetical example code off-topic for
  CR?_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: I don't see what is hypothetical about this code.

Comment: I'll vote for `sumx` as "better", although I'm sure the compiler will generate identical code for both cases.  `sumx` is just a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Instead of hard-coding the array length as 4, write `sizeof myArray / sizeOf myArray[0]`.

Since you are using C99, the first parameter should be `const int *arr`.  The second parameter might be better as `size_t size` — the `size_t` is an idiomatic way to indicate that it's an array size.

Your `sumx()` looks straightforward.  It would look slightly cooler as `sum += arr[i];`.

Your `sum()`, on the other hand, feels awkward, even if it works.  I think one reason may be that you have both `++i` and `arr = arr + 1`.  It's also a bit trickier since the pointer that supposedly points to the array keeps shifting.  If you are going to play that trick, then I'd write it this way, with the invariant that `arr + size` always points to the same place just beyond the end.  `sumx()` is still better, though.

```
int sum(const int *arr, size_t size) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (size-- > 0) {
        sum += *arr++;  
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why use the local variable ssize instead of size?

Comment: @dmuir I was worried about the fact that `size_t` is unsigned. But it actually does work, so `ssize_t` is not needed after all.

Answer (score 3):

`sumx` is better than `sum` because

- `sum` has two statements to be executed in the loop while `sumx` has just one.
- Using `[i]` is actually much easier to understand than `*` and then incrementing in the next line.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `sum + *arr` vs. `sum + arr[i]` battle, consider both approaches can easily overflow.  Even if the mathematical sum may be in an `int` range, intermediate sums may not.

```
// Leave details of finding best wider type, if any, to another post.
typedef long long int2x;

// int sumx2(int *arr, int size) {  // Suggest const array
int sumx2(const int *arr, int size) {
    int2x sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return (int) sum;
}
```